# How to derive formula for determinant of circulant Hankel matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How does one show, by applying the properties of determinants (adding multiple of a column/row to another, factoring out a constant, etc.), that

$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & ... & n \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & ... & 1 \\ 
3 & 4 & 5 & ... & 2 \\ 
{\vdots}& {\vdots}& {\vdots} & {\vdots} & {\vdots} \\ 
n & 1 & 2 & ... & n-1  \notag 
\end{vmatrix} = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\frac{n^n+n^{n-1}}{2} $$

When summing over any column or row, one gets a column/row of equal entries, namely $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. How would one proceed from there on to find the remaining terms?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065461/determinant-of-a-hankel-matrix-with-sequence-1-2-3-n-1-2-n-1) question is related, but doesn't reveal the strategy to solve the determinant, i.e. finding the formula.

Comment: First step: Subtract each row from the next one.

Comment: Yielding $$ \begin{vmatrix} 
\frac{n(n+1)}{2} & 2 & 3 & ... & n \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1-n \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\ 
{\vdots}& {\vdots}& {\vdots} & {\vdots} & {\vdots} \\ 
0 & 1-n & 1 & ... & 1  \notag 
\end{vmatrix} $$, right?

Comment: Correct. The second step should be something like that but with columns (strating from the second).

Comment: \begin{vmatrix}  \frac{n(n+1)}{2} & 2 & 1 & ... & 1 \\  0 & 1 & 0 & ... & -n \\  0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\  {\vdots}& {\vdots}& {\vdots} & {\vdots} & {\vdots} \\  0 & 1-n & n & ... & 0  \notag  \end{vmatrix}

Comment: Note that you can get rid of the first column and first row by Laplace expansion.

Comment: Laplace expansion along first column yields $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & -n \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ {\vdots}& {\vdots} & {\vdots} & {\vdots} & {\vdots} \\ 1-n & n & 0 &... & 0  \notag  \end{vmatrix}$$